# Why should we use NSOperationQueue?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

1) Why should we use `NSOperationQueue`?

2) What is advantage when we use it?

3) Can we achieve multiple synchronous web operations through `NSOperationQueue` at the same time?

4) Why do we use `NSOperationQueue` in lazy-loading of `UITableView`? Is it not possible to do it without `NSOperationQueue`?

Comment: Read about Operation Queues in [Concurrency Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: That's a grip of questions there partner. NSOperationQueue is not the only way to do a lot of those things, so maybe check out the concurrency guide and see if you can't focus your question a little bit more afterwards.

Comment: Try to ask the question in more better way in future.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Why should we use NSOperationQueue?

You should use `NSOperationQueue` to achieve concurrency when the unit of work is an `NSOperation` or one of its subclasses.  Or with other API's that require an `NSOperationQueue`, e.g. the `addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock:` method on `NSNotificationCenter`

> What is advantage when we use it?

When the unit of work to perform asynchronously can be encapsulated in an `NSOperation` object. Perhaps you're asking what is the advantage over other asynchronous API's?  There it's largely, but not entirely, a question of the level of abstraction you need and are comfortable with managing.     As [one author put it](http://eschatologist.net/blog/?p=232): *"Always use the highest-level abstraction available to you, and drop down to lower-level abstractions when measurement shows that they are needed."*

> Can we achieve multiple synchronous web operations through NSOperationQueue at the same time?

Of course.  See numerous tutorials online that address this very subject. Like [this one](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/02/16/cocoa-tutorial-nsoperation-and-nsoperationqueue/) by the estimable Marcus Zarra.

> Why do we use NSOperationQueue in lazyloading of Tableview?

For the same reason as you would use any concurrent technique.  To make the work faster and/or avoid blocking the UI.  In the case you cite, it's chiefly about not blocking the UI with a long-running task.

> Is it not possible to do it without NSOperationQueue?

Sure it's possible.  `NSThread`, GCD, etc.

Comment: Great Answer Mr NSBum :)